# In Laravel, I could not retrieve uploaded image. I created the storage link. But it wont work.Did I miss anything?

Tags: php, laravel

The image is showing as "Image Description". How I can retrieve the image which is in the database? Other than images all are smoothly working.

This is my first project. I could not find out the issue. Can anyone give a hand to sort out it?

This is my **index.blade.php**

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-sm position-relative z-index-2 flex-row overflow-auto overflow-md-visble">
    @foreach($products as $p)
    <li class="list-group-item py-2 px-3 px-xl-4 px-wd-5 flex-horizontal-center shadow-on-hover-1 rounded-0 border-top-0 border-bottom-0 flex-shrink-0 flex-md-shrink-1">

        <a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
            <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="/storage/admin/{{ $p ['prod_image_path'] }}" alt="Image Description">
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</h6>
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_price'] }}</h6>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item py-2 px-3 px-xl-4 px-wd-5 flex-horizontal-center shadow-on-hover-1 rounded-0 border-top-0 border-bottom-0 flex-shrink-0 flex-md-shrink-1">
        <a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="d-block py-2 text-center">
            <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="/storage/admin/{{ $p ['prod_image_path'] }}" alt="Image Description">
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</h6>
            <h6 class="font-size-14 mb-0 atext font-weight-semi-bold">{{ $p ['prod_price'] }}</h6>
        </a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

This is my ProductsController.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

         
    public function index()
    {
        $arr['products'] = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.index')->with($arr);
    }

   

   
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.products.create');
    }

  
    public function store(Request $request, Product $product, Category $category)
    {

        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }

        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file; 
       
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
       
    }

  
    public function show($id)
    {
       $product = Product::find($id);
       return view ('user.show',['product'=>$product]);
    }
  

    public function edit(Product $product)
    {
        $arr['product'] = $product;
        return view('admin.products.edit')->with($arr);

    }

   
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        if($request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName())
        {
            $ext =$request->prod_image_path->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
            $request->prod_image_path->storeAs('public/admin',$file);
        }else{
            $file ='';
        }
        $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
        $product-> prod_meta_title = $request-> prod_meta_title;
        $product-> prod_description = $request-> prod_description;
        $product-> prod_category = $request-> prod_category;
        $product-> prod_price = $request-> prod_price;
        $product-> prod_discount = $request-> prod_discount;
        $product-> prod_image_path = $file;
        $product->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }

    
    public function destroy($id)
    {
       Product:: destroy($id);
       return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }
}
```

And my image path is as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Where's your index method? In any case, your image path is `$file`, and I dont think it has the full path in it.

Comment: Did you link your storage folder to be publicly accessible by running `php artisan storage:link`? If so, you'll probably only need to add the correct prefi to the url. What's the current output of your index method?

Comment: I attached screenshot above.Please have a look.

Comment: Did you make the symbolic link? If so then create it again `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get the image by using the setter method on the Model class which return the full path or null(in case of no image)

**Product.php**

```
<?php
use Storage;
class Product extends Model
{
    // .. other information.
    public function getProdImagePathAttribute(){
        return $this->attributes['prod_image_path'] ? Storage::url('admin/'.$this->attributes['prod_image_path']) : null;
    }
}
```

**products.blade.php**

```
@if($p['prod_image_path'])
  <img class="img-fluid mb-1 max-width-100-sm" src="{{URL::asset($p['prod_image_path'])}}"" alt="Image Description">

@else
  <img src="{{URL::asset('admin/default-product.jpg')}}" alt="default-pic">
@endif
```